# how can modify or add new item into generic list of strings

Tags: c#

i want to remove some pretty words in list of words.

```
public System.String CleanNoiseWord(System.String word)
{
    string key = word;
    if (word.Length <= 2)
        key = System.String.Empty;
    else 
        key = word;
    //other validation here
    return key;
}

public IList<System.String> Clean(IList<System.String> words)
{
    var oldWords = words;
    IList<System.String> newWords = new string[oldWords.Count()];
    string key;
    var i = 0;
    foreach (System.String word in oldWords)
    {
        key = this.CleanNoiseWord(word);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            newWords.RemoveAt(i);
            newWords.Insert(i++, key);
        }
    }
    return newWords.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

but i can't add, remove or insert any thing in list! and exception NotSupportedException occured >> Collection was of a fixed size. how i can modify or add new item into generic list of strings?

Comment: Listen to the people that said this needs rewritten. Returning a sentinel value from a confusingly named function is a very bad way to perform what seems to be a simple boolean operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong.  Instead of

```
IList<System.String> newWords = new string[oldWords.Count()];
```

Make this

```
IList<System.String> newWords = new List<String>();
```

You do not need to initialize to a certain size with a generic list.

Answer (score 9):

Of course LINQ could make it nice and easy:

```
return words.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CleanNoiseWord(p))
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

Of course we could take this one step further and inline the function call to `CleanNoiseWord` and drastically simplify your `Clean` method:

```
public IList<System.String> Clean(IList<System.String> words)
{
    return words.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p) && p.Length > 2)
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
}
```

If no words meet the criteria in the predicate then an empty list will be returned. If you are passing a very large list and want to [lazy evaluate it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pedram/lazy-evaluation-in-c) ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution)) then remove the `ToList()` from the end - this way actual evaluation of the list will not be performed until you convert it to an actual list. (To be fair, [here's a blog post](https://www.softwire.com/blog/2012/08/13/dont-be-too-lazy-linqs-lazy-evaluation-gotchas/) about some of the gotchas of lazy (deferred) evaluation).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you create a method

```
  bool IsNoiseWord(string word)
```

and do this:

```
  words.RemoveAll(IsNoiseWord);
```

edit: this will only work for actual lists, otherwise

```
 return words.Where(x=>!IsNoiseWord(x)).Distinct().ToList()
```

Comment: +1 This seems to be the best answer if he can use List instead of IList.

Answer (score 3):

As already said, array is a fixed size list. Use the List instead.

```
IList<string> newWords = new List<string>(oldWords);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert items into a fixed size list, a happy medium would be to create a new list and insert as you "clean".

Answer (score 1):

Following Mike's answer,

```
public bool IsNoise(String word) 
{     
    return (word.Length <= 2) && validation2 && validation3;    
} 

public List<String> Clean(List<String> words) 
{ 
    words.RemoveAll(IsNoise);
    return words;
}
```